# Normalising energy data using weather data?

Tags: normalization

I'm currently doing some research into energy use, and normalising it is critical for comparison across years.

I'm considering ways to normalise the daily data (kWh) so that I can run statistical tests, however the standard Heating Degree Day method is lacking for daily normalising (better weekly and monthly).

Has anyone explored any alternative ways of normalising energy use?

Eds. with further information:

- There's a linear relationship between kWh and outdoor air temperature, so when comparing energy use (dependent on the occupats behaviour rather than weather) across years it's necessary to normalise for a comparison (otherwise colder winter leads to more energy use).
- Scale for outdoor temperatures range between -5 and 35C.
- Due to energy use being so linked to weather, a statistical analysis of change in kWh between periods A, B and C needs to be normalised to be comparable.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the normalization, such as scale range e.g., (-1, 1). And why do you want to do the normalization? I don't think statistical test needs normalized data. It seems you want to decompose the data.

Comment: Sure thing, Joey - have added more information in the original question. I haven't come across data decomposition before, will read up!

Comment: You may have a look at the FWL-theorem: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/201919/utility-of-the-frisch-waugh-theorem